# How to find interval with most overlap in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, intervals, intersection, overlap

Suppose I have four intervals:

```
a = pd.Interval(0, 2)
b = pd.Interval(1, 2)
c = pd.Interval(0, 1.1)
d = pd.Interval(-1,-0.5)
```

The most common/frequent overlap is between 1 and 1.1, since that's covered by all `a`, `b` and `c` (three of the four above).

How can I find this given a list of N intervals? Ideally I want a function that can take in a list of the 4 above intervals, and return `pd.Interval(1, 1.1)` as the output.

Answer (score 2):

I supposed you're trying to get the interval that is contained in most other intervals, because the interval with most common overlaps is `(-1,1.1]` instead of `(1,1.1]`, I don't know if maybe 
I'am wrong, but using [pd.IntervalsIndex.overlaps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.overlaps.html) I got this:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

a = pd.Interval(0, 2)
b = pd.Interval(1, 2)
c = pd.Interval(0, 1.1)
d = pd.Interval(-1,-0.5)
ls=[a,b,c,d]
indexinter = pd.IntervalIndex(ls)
print(indexinter.overlaps(pd.Interval(1, 1.1)))
print('Interval (1,1.1] overlaps ',sum(indexinter.overlaps(pd.Interval(1, 1.1))),' of 4')
print('\n')
print(indexinter.overlaps(pd.Interval(-1, 1.1)))
print('Interval (-1,1.1] overlaps ',sum(indexinter.overlaps(pd.Interval(-1, 1.1))),' of 4')
```

Output:

```
[ True  True  True False]
Interval (1,1.1] overlaps  3  of 4


[ True  True  True  True]
Interval (-1,1.1] overlaps  4  of 4
```

Nonethless, to get the interval that is contained in most other intervals, you could try this:

### First option

```
import pandas as pd
import portion as P

d = pd.Interval(0, 2)
b = pd.Interval(1, 2)
c = pd.Interval(0, 1.1)
a = pd.Interval(-1,-0.5)

def getmaxoverlapwrap(ls,inter):
    intervals=[P.openclosed(i.left, i.right) for i in ls]
    for i in intervals[1:]:
        newinter=inter&i
        if newinter.empty==False:
            inter=newinter     
    return inter
def getmaxoverlap(ls):
    intervals=[P.openclosed(i.left, i.right) for i in ls]
    ls1=[getmaxoverlapwrap(ls,i) for i in intervals]
    index = list(map(lambda x: sum([(x in s) for s in ls]), ls1)).index(max(list(map(lambda x: sum([(x in s) for s in ls]), ls1))))
    return ls1[index]
ls=[a,b,c,d]
indexinter = pd.IntervalIndex(ls)
print(getmaxoverlap(ls))
```

You have to install library [`portion`](https://pypi.org/project/portion/) (formerly distributed as python-intervals), that is a library that provides us data structure and operations for intervals in Python 3.5+, such as: -Support intervals of any (comparable) objects, -Closed or open, finite or (semi-)infinite intervals, -Interval sets (union of atomic intervals) are supported, -Automatic simplification of intervals, etc.

### Second option

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

a = pd.Interval(0, 2)
b = pd.Interval(1, 2)
c = pd.Interval(0, 1.1)
d = pd.Interval(-1,-0.5)

def getmostcontained(ls):
    indexinter = pd.IntervalIndex([pd.Interval(inter.left, inter.right, closed='both') for inter in ls])
    rights = [i.right for i in ls]
    lefts=[i.left for i in ls]
    allcomb = [pd.Interval(i[0],i[1]) for i in list(set(list(product(lefts, rights)))) if i[0]<=i[1]]
    count=0
    maxi=sum(indexinter.contains(allcomb[0].left))+sum(indexinter.contains(allcomb[0].right))
    for i in allcomb:
        newmaxi=sum(indexinter.contains(i.left))+sum(indexinter.contains(i.right))

        if newmaxi>maxi:
            count=allcomb.index(i)

    return allcomb[count]

ls=[a,b,c,d]
print(getmostcontained(ls))
```

### Third option

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Interval(0, 2)
b = pd.Interval(1, 2)
c = pd.Interval(0, 1.1)
d = pd.Interval(-1,-0.5)

def getmaxoverlap(ls):
    indexinter = pd.IntervalIndex(ls)
    start=ls[0].left
    end=ls[0].right
    checkstart=sum(indexinter.contains(start+0.00000000099))
    checkend=sum(indexinter.contains(end))


    for i in ls:
        if sum(indexinter.contains(i.left+0.000000000099))>checkstart:
            checkstart=sum(indexinter.contains(i.left+0.000000000099))
            start=i.left
        if sum(indexinter.contains(i.right))>checkend:
            checkend=sum(indexinter.contains(i.right))
            end=i.right

    return pd.Interval(start, end)

ls=[a,b,c,d]
print(getmostcontained(ls))
```

Output of all options:

```
(1,1.1]
```

The first option took `0.025967300000047544 seconds` to run 100 times the script, and took `27.19270740000138 seconds` to run 100000 times the script, he second option took `0.15769210000144085 seconds` to run 100 times the script, and took `115.13360900000043 seconds` to run 100000 times the script, and third option took `0.08970480000061798 seconds` to run 100 times the script, and took `107.52801619999991 seconds` to run 100000 times the script. The difference is almost not noticeable maybe, at least for the second and third options, but here are the time stamps I got just so you know and choose one.